# I'm having trouble displaying output on my python code for network monitoring. Not displaying result but no error

Tags: python, django, networking

I have a project that needs to monitor all the connected devices over the network. Data must be displayed in Django. I have this code no error but not displaying anything. I don't know if I have missed something.

network_tag.py

```
import sys
import logging
import netifaces as ni
import nmap
import threading
import socket
import subprocess
from django import template
from collections import namedtuple
register = template.Library()

deviceTuple = namedtuple('deviceTuple',
                      'ip, mac')

class NetworkScanner(template.Node):
    """docstring for NetworkScanner."""

    def get_interfaces(self):
        #log.info('Getting local interfaces...')
        interfaces = []
        for interface in ni.interfaces():
            if not interface.startswith(('lo', 'vir')):
                #log.info('Found local interface {}'.format(interface))
                interfaces.append(interface)
        return interfaces

    def get_local_ip(self):
        interfaces = self.get_interfaces()
        #log.info('Getting local ip address...')
        for interface in interfaces:
            try:
                addr = ni.ifaddresses(interface)[2][0]['addr']
                #log.info('Local ip address is {}'.format(addr))
                return addr
            except KeyError:
                #log.debug('Error: No local ip addresses found.')
                return ''

    def get_subnet(self):
        ip = self.get_local_ip()
        subnet = '.'.join(ip.split('.')[:3]) + '.0/24'
        #log.info('Subnet is {}'.format(subnet))
        return subnet

    def render(self, context):

        subnet = self.get_subnet()
        #log.info('Getting devices on subnet {}...'.format(subnet))
        nmap_args = '-sP'
        scanner = nmap.PortScanner()
        scanner.scan(hosts=subnet, arguments=nmap_args)

        devices = list()
        for ip in scanner.all_hosts():
            if 'mac' in scanner[ip]['addresses']:
                mac = scanner[ip]['addresses']['mac'].upper()
                #device = {'ip': ip, 'mac':mac}
                #log.info('Found device {}'.format(device))
                devices.append(deviceTuple(
                        ip=ip.ip,
                        mac=ip.mac))
        #log.info('Found {} devices'.format(len(devices)))
        #return devices


        all_stats = {
            'devices': devices
        }

        context.update(all_stats)

        return ''

@register.tag
def get_system_stats(parser, token):
    return NetworkScanner()
```

index.html

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}
{% load network_tag %}
{% block content %}
{% get_system_stats %}
<style>
    .graph { 
        background-color: #B1D632;
        position: relative;
        width: 98%; 
        border: 1px solid #666;
        padding: 1px;
    }
    .graph .bar { 
        display: block;
        padding: 1px;
        position: relative;
        background: #ff0002;
        text-align: center; 
        color: #ffffff;
        height: 1em; 
        line-height: 1em;
    }
    .graph .bar span { position: absolute; left: 1em; }
</style>

{% if user.is_superuser %}
<div class="module">

    <p>Test 1:  {{ devices.mac }}</p>

</div>
{% endif %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Result must be:
all ip addresses scanned an its mac address equivalence

Answer (score 0):

Devices is a `list`, so `{{devices.mac}}` will be undefined. Try putting it in a loop:

```
{% for device in devices %}<p>{{ device.mac }}</p>{% endfor %}
```

If that doesn't work, just add `{{devices}}` and see whether that renders anything.

Comment: Thanks for answering Patryk. I'll try your solution. Will update you. Cheers

Comment: still no output. hmmm